# How should I resolve my appspot backup failure?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to make a backup but it won't:

```
2011-10-01 09:22:43.706 /remote_api 302 5ms 0cpu_ms 0kb

213.89.134.0 - - [01/Oct/2011:05:22:43 -0700] "GET /remote_api HTTP/1.1" 302 0 - - "montaoproject.appspot.com" ms=6 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000032

$ python ./appcfg.py download_data --application=montaoproject --url=http://montaoproject.appspot.com/remote_api --filename=montao.data
Downloading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20111001.122234
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20111001.122234.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20111001.122234.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to montaoproject.appspot.com/remote_api
Please enter login credentials for montaoproject.appspot.com
Email: niklasro
Password for niklasro: 
[INFO    ] Authentication Failed
```

app.yaml:

```
- url: /remote_api
  script: remote_api.py

remote_api.py:

from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import handler
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

import re


MY_SECRET_KEY = 'thetopsecret'


cookie_re = re.compile('^"([^:]+):.*"$')


class ApiCallHandler(handler.ApiCallHandler):
    def CheckIsAdmin(self):
        login_cookie = self.request.cookies.get('dev_appserver_login', '')
        match = cookie_re.search(login_cookie)
        if (match and match.group(1) == MY_SECRET_KEY
            and 'X-appcfg-api-version' in self.request.headers):
            return True
        else:
            self.redirect('/_ah/login')
            return False


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('.*', ApiCallHandler)])


def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Update**
The server status is 302 and the method in `remote_api.py`is not reached:

```
2011-11-08 09:02:40.214 /remote_api?rtok=935015419683 302 12ms 0kb

213.89.134.0 - - [08/Nov/2011:03:02:40 -0800] "GET /remote_api?rtok=935015419683 HTTP/1.1" 302 0 - - "montaoproject.appspot.com" ms=13 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000026
```

Comment: I assume this is not specific to `download_data` as it seems to be an authentication problem - have you tried any other commands supported by `appcfg.py`, eg `update`, `download_app`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using this approach to get remote API to work with open ID (from http://blog.notdot.net/2010/06/Using-remote-api-with-OpenID-authentication), I think you need to specify the secret key (ie 'thetopsecret') as the email when prompted (and then just hit enter when prompted for the password).

Comment: I tried all that according to instructions and authentication still fails.

Answer (score 1):

Use correct credentials. niklasro is not your email address.

Comment: Correct credentials to make this solution work would be - Email: thetopsecret Password: <blank> (password is not required)

Answer (score 1):

If your app is using the High-replication datastore then your App-ID will be 's~montaoproject' (and probably needs to be in quotes on the command line? It certainly won't hurt to do so...).

Comment: It also fails using this alternative App-ID. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`[INFO    ] Authentication Failed`

It is nothing to do with GAE core , Authentication failed => either your login request failed or you are not providing the right credentials .

You are working behind proxy ? https is trouble behind squid proxy .

Comment: The response is a status 302 as I see from the log file. It seems the request doesn't reach the handler since I added debugging output the does not appear in the log.

Answer (score 0):

MY_SECRET_KEY corresponds with your login, not your password.  You shouldn't need to actually enter a password (just hit return).  So when you authenticate use:

```
Email: thetopsecret
Password for thetopsecret: (nothing)
```